# checking condition in a for loop by ++i

Tags: c, loops

Here is a **C program:**

```
int main()
{
   short int i = 0;

   for( ; ++i ; )          // <-- how this is checking condition 
     printf("%u,", i);

   return 0;
}
```

from the above program I thought that this will go for an **endless loop** as in `for()` there is nothing to check the condition and to come out from loop.

but **I was wrong**, it is **not an endless loop**.

**My question:**
How `for( ; ++i ; )` is checking condition in the above program?

Comment: Try turning on optimization :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The program is wrong as it overflows a signed int, which is undefined behavior in C. In some environments it *will* result in an endless loop, but many compilers implement signed overflow the same way they implement unsigned overflow.

In case signed overflow is implementd like unsigned overflow, at some point `i` will become too big to fit into a short and will **wrap around** and become 0 - which will break the loop. Basically `USHRT_MAX + 1` yields 0.

So change `i` to `unsigned short i = 0` and it will be fine.

Comment: However, changing it to an unsigned integer will make it overflow at a larger value.

Comment: Last line mean then it will endless?

Comment: Even if an implementation "implements" signed overflow by wrapping (this will usually naturally happen simply because it's hard not to), the compiler should still optimize OP's code to an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( init, condition, inc )
```

Your "condition" is `i++` . When `i++` equals 0 it exits. With a short it happens quite fast.

Do `for ( ; ;i++)` for endless loop

Comment: Actually, condition in OP is `++i`, but this answer is essentially correct when combined with wraparound overflow.

Comment: sorry, `++i` and `i++` have the same effect here. For the "wraparound", it might be worth mentionning that `i` will be negative before reaching 0. It will not "wrap around to 0" but wrap around to -32768 . Then increment to 0 and stop.

Comment: `if (++i)` is not the same as `if (++i)`

Comment: "it might be worth mentionning that i will be negative before reaching 0": what are you waiting for?